# how to put nested case-when condition in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, nested, case-when

i want to write nested case when condition in query to store the value that will come from one case when condition and another case when condition into same new column.to get this kind of result i am writing the query as:

```
(case when sq_name_new1 like format('%%%s%%',demo.name) THEN count(sq_name_new1) else (when demo.empcode is not null then count(demo.id) End) END) AS indivisual from res_scheduledjobs
```

in the above query demo.name column comes from CTE.so my whole query look like:

```
with demo(empcode,id,name) as               
(select hr_employee.emp_code,hr_employee.id,concat(resource_resource.name,' ',hr_employee.middle_name,' ',hr_employee.last_name) as name from hr_employee inner join  resource_resource on resource_resource.id=hr_employee.resource_id)
select demo.empcode,demo.name,sq_name_new1,(case when sq_name_new1 like format('%%%s%%',demo.name) THEN count(sq_name_new1) else (when demo.empcode is not null then count(demo.id) End) END) AS indivisual from res_scheduledjobs LEFT JOIN demo on demo.id=res_scheduledjobs.assigned_technician group by res_scheduledjobs.assigned_technician,sq_name_new1,demo.empcode,demo.name ;
```

i just want to store the count of (sq_name_new1) column into INDIVISUAL Column and the count of (demo.id) column into same column,that is in INDIVISUAL,if the first case condition does not match.
but when i am executing my query it throw an error.that is,something is wrong in the syntax of case when condition.

please help me yo write the correct nested case-when condition.

Comment: Just use `CASE WHEN <condition1> THEN ... WHEN <condition2> THEN ... ELSE <else>` ... but you should format your query and there may be other problems there.

Answer (score 51):

`CASE ... WHEN ... END` is an expression. It can be nested like any other expression.

```
CASE
     WHEN condition THEN
         CASE
             WHEN othercondition THEN
                 ....
         END
END
```

Comment: Should I add the `;` behind `END` of nested `CASE WHEN` inside?

Comment: @TaurusDang No, good catch. I forgot I was not writing pl/pgsql. Fixed.

Answer (score 9):

The first semicolon `;` should be removed as in @Craig Ringer's answer.

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN condition1 THEN
    CASE
      WHEN condition1.1 THEN
        ...
    END
  END AS column_name
FROM table_name;
```